Samba Multiple Locations One Share
Is it possible to create a share in samba that uses two or more folders and combines them into a single shared folder that displays the content of both locations in one or is there another method of doing this?
This would be a read only share.
I have a lot of media shared on my network and I need to add some more storage but having two shares for each location would just be a pain and RAID is out of the question.

Nope.  You will need to copy all those files to a 3rd location (dir or mount point) that holds all.  Only way I can imagine this to work is to code your own command using a coding language.
